# Access POSIX IPC message queue using PHP

Tags: php, message-queue

There are PHP functions available to create/read/write System V message queues. But I did not find any solution to access (create/read/write) POSIX IPC message queues using PHP.
Is there a PHP extension that wraps the POSIX message queue functions?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has extensions for process control that are not enabled by default, so they should be installed manually.

You might want to check the full list of extensions here: [Process Control Extensions on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.process.php).

For Semaphore, Shared Memory and IPC extension check here: [Semaphores on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php)

Hope it helps.